# Animating the foreground color

Tags: nativescript

Can I animate the foreground color (i.e. text color) in Nativescript.

I can't seem to get it to work.

background-color is working.

`@keyframes session-favorite-selected {
    from { transform: scale(1, 1) rotate(120); opacity: 0; animation-timing-function: linear; background-color: white; color: red; }
    to { transform: scale(1, 1) rotate(0); opacity: 1; background-color: green; color: white; }

}`

Comment: At the moment NativeScript lets you animate the follow `opacity`, `backgroundColor`, `translateX`, `translateY`
`scaleX`, `scaleY`, `rotate` as it is described in the documentation - https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/animation. animating the `color` property is not supported.

Comment: Please add that ASAP. Mainly because many apps now use FontAwesome as icons and want to animate the 'image' which is really a font letter. Thanks.